# How to install an OpenERP module and its dependencies?

Tags: odoo

My directory, cloned from github, contains 112 OpenERP (Odoo) modules. What is the best way to install these modules? I have tried by copying module by module to addons directory and then using Settings in OpenERP to install modules. The installation process complained that there are dependencies, modules on which the current module depends. Is there a way to install module and its dependencies all at once? I am using Odoo v8.

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to install the dependent module to install manually. OpenERP will automatically installs the dependent module if those modules are not installed.

The only thing is system should be able to find those module at the appropriate location.

I am wondering why you needed to copy the modules to 'addons' directory, because as you are saying you have cloned the git, modules should be there in the addons directory already.

If the modules that you are trying to install are some community/custom module which are not included in git cloned odoo repo, than you need to include path of those modules in the odoo system variable 'addons_path', which will tell the system to include those modules during finding of modules.

Comment: Thank you, Hardik, sounds logical, and the approach you outlined will most likely work. I will try it. Can you please tell me the location of the variable 'addons_path'? I hope I will know how to change it once I know where it is..

Comment: OpenERP uses several configuration parameters to start, one of them is the 'addons_path', which you can locate under 'odoo directory -> openerp -> tools -> config.py' between the line no 452 to 460. Here you can add path of your module along with the other core modules. Make sure you append to the 'addons_path' don't override it (comma separated). The other better way to start OpenERP server is to use 'config' file. Try to search for config file for Odoo, you will get to know how to use it. It include several other configuration parameters which is used by Odoo.

Comment: I have found the configuration file at /opt/odoo/odoo/debian/openerp-server.conf and added the path so the variable looks like: addons_path = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons,/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/odoomrp_wip. But I still cannot see the modules after I click "Update Modules List" in "Settings". I also restarted the server.

Comment: Also it is not clear to me where to add new path in config.py - I have found addons_path place but there are no paths specified in the code and I am not sure where to add my new modules path.

Comment: If you have found the openerp-server.conf file, than you don't need to add the path in config.py file. Now the thing is while starting the server you need to specify this openerp-server.conf file as `python openerp-server --config=/opt/odoo/odoo/debian/openerp-server.conf`.

Comment: In my openerp-server.conf file I have "addons_path = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons,/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/odoomrp_wi‌​p". But, my core modules are at "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/"  (this is the location of addons that OpenERP sees it in Settings/Local Modules) which is different than "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons" in the variable. I am hesitant to run the command you mentioned because of this. Am I wrong? I need to be sure.

Comment: Whatever path you have, they all have to be added, separated by comma. You can modify the config file as per your need. Try to add all path in this file whatever paths you have it. Then try to run the server using that file. The path in the file is may be default given by odoo, you can of-course modify it.

Comment: I am wondering where the Odoo finds the information that the modules are in /opt/odoo/odoo/addons? This is not specified in openerp-server.conf file. I am not sure which modules will be loaded if I specify two paths for the addons modules. Odoo pulls the information about modules currently, from somewhere, but I don't know where from. Maybe that's the place to add new modules path.

Comment: In the openerp-server there should be a parameter addons_path, which will tell the system which modules are to be taken into consideration. Try to read the documentation for starting the server, because you need someone around to guide you and by this way it is not possible to solve your problem. Hope you understand.

Comment: I know how to restart the server, I am just worried since the openerp-server.conf has "addons_path = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons" while the Odoo is using "opt/odoo/odoo/addons" why is that? How Odoo knows that the path is "opt/odoo/odoo/addons" if it's not written anywhere. That's the point of my confusion.

Comment: Thanks, Hardik, for your answer, I marked it as solved.